# MySQL error in Perl ( Errorcode 2)

Tags: mysql, perl

I am complete newbie in Perl. I have this little sub

```
sub processOpen{
    my($filename, $mdbh)=@_;
    my($qr, $query);

    # parse filename to get the date extension only
    # we will import the data into the table with this extension
    # /home//logs/open.v7.20120710_2213.log
    my(@fileparts) = split(/\./, $filename);
    my(@filedateparts) = split(/_/, $fileparts[2]);
    my($tableext) = $filedateparts[0];


    $query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '" . $filename . "' INTO TABLE open_" . $tableext . " FIELDS TERMINATED BY '||' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
              (open_datetime, open_date, period,tag_id)";

    $qr = $$mdbh->prepare($query);
    $qr->execute(); # causes error (see below)
    $qr->finish();
}
```

And I'm getting the following error:

> `DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Can't get stat of '/home/logs/open..v7.20120710_2213.log' (Errcode: 2) at /home/thisfile.pm line 32.`

Line 32 is the `$qr->execute();`

Comment: It's a gobbledegook version of "file not found". Either mysql doesn't have the permissions to reach down that directory tree, or the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you, but the file is there, perms are correct....

Comment: Is the filename `open..v7`... with two dots, or `open.v7`... with one dot?

Comment: So did you type the error message wrong? Or did you pass the wrong `$filename` argument to your subroutine?

Comment: I missed "DBD::" at the beginning of the error message.

Comment: do "print $query" before using it.

Comment: Looks like i got it to work with "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE....."
I have to leave for a few hours now, but when i get back, I will thoroughly test it and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Error Code 2 is most likely "File not found".

Does your file exist?  Note that if you are running the perl on a separate host from the MySQL database, the file must be on the database host, not the client host.